# Ubuntu 18.04 not stable on Asus ZenBook UX533FD

Tags: 18.04, asus, compatibility

I recently received my new computer, an Asus Zenbook UX533FD-A9034T. As I didn't want to use Microsoft Windows, I created a bootable USB key with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version and replaced windows OS with it on my new computer. Everything worked fine for the installation and the system is booting properly.

However, after I login, the systems freezes, my touchpad is no longer working, my keyboard is not working properly, all clicks (using an external mouse) are really slow and I can't do anything... I'm forced most of the time to reboot using alt + PrtScreen + B.

As the same version worked on another older computer, I guess this comes from the compatibility between Ubuntu and my Asus hardware but I tried to update drivers and did a lot of research on internet without any success :(

Any help is welcome, feel free to ask any question on the behaviour of the system.

Comment: If you've not done so already, please update the BIOS version as this may be the main cause of any installation problems. Also, if issues persist with Ubuntu 18.04.2, please consider upgrading the kernel from 4.XX to 5.XX. I'll note that Ubuntu 19.04 comes with kernel 5.XX and all drivers work well on an ASUS UX433FN.

Answer (score 3):

I made a reddit post about this computer https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/ajdog3/asus_ux533fd_and_linux/

I installed xubuntu 18.04 on it, and it did work. There is no reason for Ubuntu 18.04 not to work.

Maybe your computer is overheating. How long is the battery life? You should get 10 hours.  To solve overheating and battery drain, you need to install the latest nvidia drivers (at the time  nvidia-driver-415), go to nvidia prime and siwth to power-saving mode.